# Partial derivatives of a complex valued real variable function

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-derivative

Let $\Delta_R$ be a disc centered at the origin on the complex plane.

Let $f:\Bbb R\to \Delta_R$ defined as,

$f(x)=u(x) + i v(x)$

The following are my questions:

$Q1)$ What can we say about $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y }$ for the points on disc?Will they be $0$?

$Q2)$ I am a little confused because, as  $\Delta_R$ is not even the domain of $f$ then how can we talk about the partial derivatives of $f$ on $\Delta_R$?

Comment: Your confusion in (Q2) is sensible: it does not make sense to talk about the two partial derivatives $\partial f / \partial x$ and $\partial f / \partial y$ of a function $f$ of only one real variable.  The only derivative I know is that if $f(x) = u(x) + iv(x)$, then $f'(x) = u'(x) + iv'(x)$.  So, I also don't know what is meant by (Q1) as it is currently stated.

Comment: @JesseMadnick I am working on some other problem and i guess the solution of that problem is somewhat connected to my above question.  The following is the actual problem I am working on: "$u$ is a real-valued function on an open disc $\Delta _ R$ (Disc with center at the origin and radius $R$) on the complex plane. Moreover $u^{-1}+iu$ is analytic on the given disc. Then show that $u$ must be a constant." So basically I have to deduce the result using the C-R Equations which involves the partial derivatives of $u^{-1}$ and that's where the problem lies. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main ideas: The actual question is in your comment. What you wrote in the question doesn't make any sense, as you yourself noticed in Q2).

You are given a real valued function $u$ in an open disc $D$ with the property that $f=u^{-1} + iu$ is analytic on $D.$ Notice that $u$ is never $0$ in $D.$ Because $f$ is analytic in $D,$ the CR equations tell us

$$ (u^{-1})_x = u_y,\,\, (u^{-1})_y = -u_x.$$

Now $(u^{-1})_x = -u^{-2}u_x,$ etc. Play around with this. Your strategy is to show $u_x=u_y \equiv 0.$

Another approach, if you know the open mapping theorem: The range of $f$ is contained in the curve $\{(1/x,x): x\in \mathbb R, x\ne 0\}.$ That is not an open set.

Comment: I though $u^{-1}$ is the inverse map of $u$ and hence I was in a dilemma regarding the partial derivatives of $u^{-1}$ on the disc.Thank you for providing clarity regarding $u^{-1}$. Moreover I am new to Complex-Analysis so I haven't yet come across Open Mapping Theorem.